# Show that given a valuation $v$ there is a unique functions $v^*: Formula(\mathcal{L}) \to \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I have a few questions in relation to valuations in first order logic. I have the following definition:

**Definition 1:** A valuation is a function $v : PFormula^{\mathcal{L}}_0 \to \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$

I am to show that given a valuation $v$ there is a unique functions $v^*: Formula(\mathcal{L}) \to \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$ such that

$$v^* \upharpoonright PFormula^{\mathcal{L}}_0  = v $$

$$v^*((\neg \varphi ))=1-v^*(\varphi)$$

$$v^*((\psi \to \varphi))=max \lbrace1-v^*(\psi), v^*(\varphi) \rbrace$$

As a hint it has been suggested that I look at the sets

$$PFormula^{\mathcal{L}}_{\leq n} = \bigcup_{0 \leq i \leq n} PFormula^{\mathcal{L}}_i$$

and by induction (on n) show that there is a unique $v^{(n)}: PFormula^{\mathcal{L}}_{\leq n} \to \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$ with the desired properties and then obtain $v^*$ by "gluing" the v's together.

I have tried to define $v^{(n)}$ such that the properties hold and prove by induction that it exist for each n but I am not sure this is the correct approach. Also I am not sure what is meant by "gluing" the functions together in the end as well.

Comment: PFormulas are atoms, I think...

Comment: Induction on the *length* $n$ of formulas (where $n$ is the number of occurrences of connectives). $n=0$ is obvious: by def $v^*$ is $v$.

Comment: The induction step must consider the two cases of $\lnot$ and $\to$. If $v^*(\varphi)$ is unique (by Induction Hypotheses) what happens to $v^*(\lnot \varphi)$? May we have two different values?

Comment: See [your previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3659966/tautologies-and-valuations-in-a-first-order-language)

Comment: The technique suggested is probably that of [Recursion on $\omega$](https://books.google.it/books?id=JlR-Ehk35XkC&pg=PA73) as well as [Recursion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#The_recursion_theorem)